# Nested PHP switch include navigation

Tags: php, navigation, include, nested, switch-statement

I’m currently working on a small web project, and my plan is to build it all from the bottom up – to start by making a functioning website which uses only PHP, HTML and CSS, and then, if the user enables it, progressively enhance the website through the magic of Javascript, more particularly - jQuery.  However, I’ve been running into some problems on the PHP side of things, and since I’m merely novice when it comes to that scripting language, what I can’t figure out is simply:

***How to implement one PHP switch include navigation inside another one?***

To better clarify what I’m trying to achieve, let me show you a little mock up of what my site structure looks like:

- Header.php (Header)
- Page1.php (Content page 1)
- Page2.php (Content page 2)
- Page3.php (Content page 3)
- Page3.1.php (Content page 3 sub-content 1)
- Page3.2.php (Content page 3 sub-content 2)
- Page3.3.php (Content page 3 sub-content 3)
- Footer.php (Footer)

As you can see, when it comes to this mock up, it’s on page 3 where I intend to nest one php navigation inside another one. This to enable some slideresque sub-navigation on that very page, but my efforts in doing that have so far been futile at best.
As far as code goes, this is what I’ve managed to scrap together.

```
<a class="link" href="index.php?id=page1">Page1</a>
<a class="link" href="index.php?id=page2"> Page2</a>
<a class="link" href=” index.php?id=page3">Page3</a>

<?php

  switch($_GET['id']) {
  default:
  include('page1.php');

  break; case "page2":
  include('page2.php');

  break; case "page3":
  include('page3.php');  // *Nested navigation goes inside this page
  }
?>
```

*Inside of page3.php I’ve put pretty much the same code, only that it links to the sub-pages of that page (page3.1.php, page3.2, and page3.3.php ) instead.

Unfortunately, this doesn’t seem to work – first of all, when I enter localhost/index.php I my web browser I get the following notice:
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-navigation\index.php on line 26.
However, when I click one of the links, or enter a url like index.php?id=page1 I don’t get that notice. So it seems like I need to define the ’id’ variable, but where and how to do that?

In addition to that, the nested navigation on page 3 doesn’t work at all, instead, when clicking on of the links to the sub-pages, I get redirected to the index page. I might have to do with the URL:s , but then again, what do I know?

Please help me figure out how to make this work - all help, even just a slight nudge in the right direction, is welcome and much appreciated- thanks in advance!

/ Johan Wendesten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning you get is about an undefined index - you are trying to access an element of an array that does not exist.  You need to change

```
switch($_GET['id']) {
```

to

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $id = "page1";
}

switch($id) {
```

For page 3, first off you may have an issue here:

```
<a class="link" href=” index.php?id=page3">Page3</a>
```

You'll notice an extra space and a weird quote (`”` vs `"` - you want `"`).

For the subpages, we'd have to see the URL's generated, but I'm guessing it has to do with the links as well - to keep with the way you are doing it, I would probably have the link look like:

```
<a class="link" href="index.php?id=page3&subid=2">Subcontent 2</a>
```

and then in the php:

```
if (isset($_GET['subid'])) {
    $subid = $_GET['subid'];
} else {
    $subid = 1;
}

switch($subid) {
```

Comment: First of all, sorry for my delayed response, but I posted this before I went to work and I'havent had time to come home and test your solution until now.

With that said, thank you very much! It all works now thanks to you explaining things - defining the index got rid of the notice and your solution for the sub-nav worked like a charm. Now, and just to clarify - the way I did it was that i put the PHP code for the sub-nav inside of page 3 and used your approach for the URL:s. Was that how you intended it? Also 'subid' in this case is arbitrary right? I went with 'slide' and it works just fine

Comment: Lastly, and if you don't mind, I have one tiny question mark that you, or somebody else might be able to straighten out for me.

When looking up this navigation method on various web design blogs and forums I've come across some individuals saying that it is not save to use. Is that true? And if so, why is that and what can I do to make it less vulnerable?

With that aksed, thanks again, and now I'm off to harvest some reputation to able to upvote your post. Cheers

Comment: It wouldn't be safe to do something like `include($_GET['id']);` because then they could include any file they wanted to.  But what you have is essentially a whitelist, I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be safe.

Answer (score 0):

my freind english is not my first language so i am reading it again, but one mistake i found in your code is this.

for the page three thats why you are having problem for the page3 link

```
<a class="link" href=” index.php?id=page3">Page3</a>
```

the href part is wrong this one href=” it should be this href=" means your href part should be this

```
href="index.php?id=page3"
```

and to remove the error for id

add if statement like this

```
if($_REQUEST=='GET'){ //all of your switch statement will come here }
```

so your code should look like this

```
<?php

//start of if statement  
if($_REQUEST=='GET'){


  switch($_GET['id']) {
  default:
  include('page1.php');

  break; case "page2":
  include('page2.php');

  break; case "page3":
  include('page3.php');  // *Nested navigation goes inside this page
  }

}//end of if statement
```